# Build an array to POST to PHP

Tags: javascript, post

As part of a larger problem I have come up with a simplified example of where I'm currently stuck.

I have a html form that uses a javascript POST of an array to a test.php file.
If I post a plain hard coded text string it works.  If I try and post an array that I have built from my form the "Hello from test" come out but the data does not. The result is visible in an alert box.

(I have commented out the plain text bit )

I don't know what I'm doing wrong?  The array looks good to me in the Chrome debugger.

Here is the html and the php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    function testResults(myform)
    {
        var outputArray =[];
        var count = 0;
        for (var inp of myform) 
        {
            if (inp.className == "portfolio")
            {
                if (inp.checked == true)
                {

                    var nameString =  inp.name;
                    var valueString = inp.value
                    outputArray[count]= nameString + ':' + '"' + valueString + '"';
                    count = count +1;
                }
            }
        }
        //alert (outputArray);

        $.post("test.php",
        {
            //blackPortfolio: "Black",
            //bluePortfolio: "Blue"
            outputArray
        },
        function(data,status)
        {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    }


    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="userForm" >

    <form name="myForm" action="BuildPostStrng.html" onsubmit="return testResults(myForm)" method="POST"> 
        <div class="CheckBoxTable">
            <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                <input type = "checkbox" class="portfolio" name = "blackPortfolio"  value = "Black" />
                <label for = "blackPortfolio">Black</label>
            </div>
            <div class="CheckBoxCell">
                <input type = "checkbox" class="portfolio" name = "bluePortfolio"  value = "Blue" />
                <label for = "bluePortfolio"> Blue </label>
            </div>
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="map" </div>
```

test.php

```js
<?php
echo 'Hello from Test.php <BR>';

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key;
  echo '<BR>';
  echo $value;
  echo '<BR>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You’re making this way to complicated - use jQuery’s `serialize` method to create data sets ready for submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the manual](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/); the `data` argument must be a *plain object or string*.

You are passing it an array, which isn't allowed.

Comment: That worked.  It is obvious once you see the answer :).  I had it stuck in my head that it was an array.  I just changed my array to a string and it worked.  I'll have a go at @CBroe 's suggestion to use serialize and post both solutions for anyone else that comes across this post.  THANKS